# Parse.com Receiving push notifications even after Logout -Android

Tags: android, session, parse-platform

I've made an app that uses Parse to send push notifications to other devices when the user is logged into his account. The problem is that the users still receive pushes even after they've logged out. 
A method to fix this would be awesome. 
Here's the code i use to register the device.

```
public void registerPushNotification() {
    ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    installation.put("user", mCurrentUser);
    installation.saveInBackground();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try this (code is in Swift, but I think it's the same)

```
PFUser.logOut()
PFInstallation.currentInstallation().removeObjectForKey("user")
PFInstallation.currentInstallation().saveInBackground()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try by calling the `ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().deleteInBackground()` at the time of logout.

Comment: Nope, still receiving.

Comment: I get the same, any ideas??

Comment: Deletion of data such as _Installation objects is not allowed from client side. You should provide a Cloud Code function to do this task, however this is not the correct approach to this problem IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using channels, with channels you can get some sort of control of pushes and so on.

The method signature is like this

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("Name of my channel", SaveCallback cb);
```

Try using this when the user logs in:

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("my_channel", new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            // Great
                        } else {
                            // Something wrong happened...
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Use this when user logs out:

```
ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground("my_channel");
```

When sending pushes query for all users who (are still) subscribed to the `"my_channel"` channel:

```
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setChannel("my_channel");
push.setMessage("Message to the subscribers of the channel!");
push.sendInBackground();
```

Make sure to check out [Parse guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications) and [docs](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParsePush.html).
Cheers!